# php execute python script and save output in session

Tags: php, python, linux

i have this php code :

```
$command = escapeshellcmd('python acn.py -c'.$username);
$output = shell_exec($command);
```

i need output the result of acn.py .. on windows get output, on linux not give output. python script work, php not print output ! Where is my wrong ? chmod +x * allready executed !

Comment: Did you echo `$output`?  Also, linux webserver user will need to use `/usr/bin/python` or whatever as a complete path.

Comment: check to make sure the same version of python is installed on your windows and linux. you also might want to put a space after -c

Comment: if im execute in console python ac.py ... script work whit out problem ! yess im corect space in original script.

Comment: Are you logged in to the console as the webserver user? `/usr/bin` is most likely not in it's path but is almost certainly in yours.

Comment: is vps runing on vps, whit root user

Comment: $command = escapeshellcmd('python /var/www/html/acn.py -c '.$username);
        $output = shell_exec($command);

same problem ...

Comment: Did you even read my comment?